# Vybrid ADC not working for first 10 milliseconds

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, adc

vybrid processor ADC ADC_HS COCO( conversion complete)  bit is not going high for first 10 milliseconds , after 10ms reinitialized and working fine. ADC read called for every one milliseconds,ADC config details:  12bit, ADIV/8, no low power , 16samples avg, normal speed , software trigger

Comment: "first 10 milliseconds" *after what*? Reset?

Comment: YES RESET ADC, ADC_init() called once at power up and later for ADC errors same ADC_init called again to reset.